# Adding touch event to html5 game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still working on this html5 game tutorial, and I'm trying to add touch events so that the game can be played on touch screen devices. I have a variable that enables the player to jump by using the space bar:

```
 var KEY_CODES = {
 32: 'space'
 };
 var KEY_STATUS = {};
 for (var code in KEY_CODES) {
 if (KEY_CODES.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
 KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[code]] = false;
  }
 }
 document.onkeydown = function(e) {
 var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
 if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
 e.preventDefault();
 KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
  }
 };
 document.onkeyup = function(e) {
 var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
 if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
 e.preventDefault();
 KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
  }
 };
```

Which is called in the update player function:

```
  player.update = function() {

  if (KEY_STATUS.space && player.dy === 0 && !player.isJumping) {
  player.isJumping = true;
  assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
  jumpCounter = 12;
  }

  if (KEY_STATUS.space && jumpCounter) {
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
  assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
  }

  jumpCounter = Math.max(jumpCounter-1, 0);

  this.advance();

  };
```

I tried to add additional functions to the KEY_CODES variable that substituted 'onkeydown' and 'onkeyup' for 'ontouch' and 'onrelease' but I haven't been able to get that to work. 
Should I continue to try and add to the KEY_CODE block or do I need to define new variables for touch?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change your jump triggering events based on device type(touch/keyboard). You will have to update your code handling keyCode to cover both cases!

```
function is_touch_device() {
  return 'ontouchstart' in window        // works on most browsers 
      || navigator.maxTouchPoints;       // works on IE10/11 and Surface
};

var JUMP_START_EVENT = is_touch_device()? 'ontouchstart' : 'onkeydown';
var JUMP_END_EVENT = is_touch_device()? 'untouchend' : 'onkeyup';

document[JUMP_START_EVENT] = function(e) {
 var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
 if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
 e.preventDefault();
 KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
  }
 };

 document[JUMP_END_EVENT] = function(e) {
 var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
 if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
 e.preventDefault();
 KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
  }
 };
```

Comment: Hi @sabithpocker, thanks so much for this. I've updated my code, and while it still works on desktop, touch isn't triggering on the iPad. Those variables and that function you've shown me are great though, so I'll see if I can get anything going with those. thanks again.